# Linq select where contains

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 objects (tried to make it work a bit like SO) with a `many to many` relationship that I would like to filter one collection of them based on the other. here are my object:

```
public class Code
{
    public int CodeId { get; set; }
    public string CodeName { get; set; }
    public string CodeData { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Code> Codes { get; set; }
}
```

So if I have a collection of `Tags` that I want to filter upon I want to return a collection of `Codes` that their `tags` includes at least one of the selected tags but that there's no `Tag` in the selected `Tags` that doesn't exist in `Code`.
[image: example]
I tried using `Linq` for it but eventually got to this non-linq solution:

```
public IEnumerable<Code> GetCodes()
    {
        //A collection to filter upon
        var SelectedTags = new List<Tag>();

        //the collction to return
        var FoundCodes = new List<Code>();

        foreach (Code code in GetAllCodes())
        {
            foreach (var tags in code.Tags)
            {
                if (SelectedTags.Contains(tags))
                {
                    if (!FoundCodes.Contains(code))
                    {
                        FoundCodes.Add(code);
                    }
                    continue;
                }
            }
            foreach (var selectedTags in SelectedTags)
            {
                if (!code.Tags.Contains(selectedTags))
                {
                    FoundCodes.Remove(code);
                }
            }
        }

        return FoundCodes;
    }
```

So my question is how do I do it with `Linq`?

Comment: SelectedTags is an empty list initially, so the condition SelectedTags.Contains(tags) will always evaluate to false, and no codes will be added to FoundCodes. Are you sure this code works for you ? Can you please elaborate more on what you are trying to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple query should do the trick (it finds all codes which has all selected tags, and no other tags): (*Note that while this code exactly mimicks the OP's implementation's behavior, it's not the desired result. See further below for the fixed version*)

```
public IEnumerable<Code> GetCodes()
{
    var SelectedTags = new List<Tag>(); /* fill this however */
    return from code in GetAllCodes() /* get all codes*/
           where SelectedTags.All(code.Tags.Contains) /* filter out codes with nonmatching tags */
           where code.Tags.All(SelectedTags.Contains) /* filter out codes with missing tags*/
           select code; /* return the remaining codes */
}
```

Note that depending on the number of different tags this could be slow without use of collections which are optimized for searching (although still a bit faster than your solution).

**Edit:** To get the result illustrated on your image (get all codes with all selected tags, regardless of other tags the code has), just omit the second where clause:

```
public IEnumerable<Code> GetCodes()
{
    var SelectedTags = new List<Tag>(); /* fill this however */
    return from code in GetAllCodes() /* get all codes*/
           where SelectedTags.All(code.Tags.Contains) /* filter out codes with nonmatching tags */
           select code; /* return the remaining codes */
}
```

Comment: +1, It appears the OP is implicitly using EF, otherwise you could use `HashSet` and the associated extensions to get better performance. After all, its seems, just a check for set equality is needed, which is O(n) between `HashSet`s.

Comment: Isn't the second `.All` should be `.Any`?

Comment: @Yoav: You can just omit it completely. See my edit for details.

Answer (score 2):

erm, how about.

```
var foundCodes = GetAllCodes()
                   .Where(code => code.Tags.All(t => SelectedTags.Contains(t)))
                   .Distinct()
                   .ToList();
```

---

If `GetAllCodes()` returns a distinct result you can omit the `Distinct` call.

---

**following on from @Nuffin's comment**,

you could try,

```
SelectedTags = SelectedTags.OrderBy(t => t).ToList();

var foundCodes = GetAllCodes()
                   .Where(code =>
                       code.Tags
                           .OrderBy(t => t)
                           .SequenceEqual(SelectTags))
                   .Distinct()
                   .ToList();
```

but, I suspect your Query Provider will be unable to translate `SequenceEqual` into a statement.

In this case, use @Nuffin's answer.

Comment: The OP's code explicitly filters out all codes with any nonmatching tags, which is missing in your solution.

Comment: this returns an `IQueryable<bool>` and not a collection of `Codes`

Comment: @Yoav, apologies, its early here. Corrected.

Comment: @Jodrell Thank you very much. the only thing missing is that is the `SelectedTags` contains a `Tag` that isn't part of the Code's Tags it shouldn't be selected.

Comment: @Yoav If a `Code` has a `Tag` that is not contained in `SelectedTags` then not **`All`** of the `Code`s tags will be contained in `SelectedTags`.

Comment: @Jodrell But if SelectedTags contains a tag that isn't in the code's tag list, the code isn't filtered out. If the selected list is `{ "a", "b", "c" }`, neither codes with `{ "a", "b", "c", "d" }` nor codes with `{ "a", "b" }` should be selected. Your code accounts for the first case, but not the second.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can shorten this so:

```
public IEnumerable<Code> GetCodes()
{
  //A collection to filter upon
  var SelectedTags = new List<Tag>();

  //the collction to return
  var FoundCodes = new List<Code>();

  foreach (var code in GetAllCodes())
  {
    foreach (var tags in code.Tags.Where(tags => SelectedTags.Contains(tags)))
    {
      if (!FoundCodes.Contains(code))
      {
        FoundCodes.Add(code);
      }
      continue;
    }
    foreach (var selectedTags in SelectedTags.Where(selectedTags => !code.Tags.Contains(selectedTags)))
    {
      FoundCodes.Remove(code);
    }
  }

  return FoundCodes;
}
```

Maybe you could post `GetAllCodes()` ... The Problem is that because of the to Loops inside the foreach i dont know how to shorten it more into a linq method chain.